# How do i dismiss the keyboard on return key from a UITextView

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

How do I dismiss the keyboard by pressing the return key on device? I know how to dismiss keyboard, but not when using the UITextView:

```
resignFirstResponder
```

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
self.messageTextView.delegate = self
```

And with this function:

```
func messageTextViewShouldReturn(textView: UITextView) -> Bool
    {
        self.messageTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: yeah just use self.textview.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: @Lamar - Use it where?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember to add the UITextDelegate into ViewDidLoad()

```
 func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n"
    {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: That does not do anything. And I am using textView, not textField.

Comment: correct function declaration is `func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

unlike a textField where IBActions are available, there are no actions available for text views.

create your textViewOutlet

If you are using a tableview:
identify where your textView row is located:

```
let textViewIndex = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
```

then in (_:didSelectRowAt:) dismiss the keyboard if any row other than your textView

```
if indexPath != textViewIndex {
                   textViewOutlet.resignFirstResponder()
               }
```

if you are not using a tableview: In your SB viewcontroller, drag a UITapGestureRecognizer to your view.  Then create an IBAction from that Tap Gesture Recognizer by control dragging it to your view.  In the action dismiss your keyboard from your textViewOutlet:

```
    @IBAction func tapGestureRecognizer(_ sender: Any) {
notesField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```